# Is my logic faulty in using the squeeze theorem for double limits? Need some tips

Tags: calculus, limits

and good day to everyone!

I have a question regarding double limits and the proof of their existence using the squeeze theorem. Let's say we have the following limit

$$\lim_{x \to 0,y\to 0}
     \left(\frac{xy} {\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\right)$$

So when switching to polar coordinates the answer is obviously zero. But, I have trouble proving that using the squeeze theorem. Here is my approach:

$$\frac{1} {\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\ge0$$ this is always true, because $x^2 + y^2 \ge0$.

Afterwards,   $$\frac{1} {\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\le\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$

Which brings us to   $$0\le\frac{1} {\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\le\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$

If we multiply both sides by $xy$ we get

$$0\le\frac{xy} {\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\le xy \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$

Then, if we take the limit of both sides (x,y)->(0,0) by the squeeze theorem we get that the limit of f(x,y) = 0.

Is this approach correct? If not, why? Can anyone give me any common guidelines and/or hints on how to apply the squeeze theorem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The inequality $\frac 1 {\sqrt {1+x^{2}}} \leq \sqrt {1+x^{2}}$ is false. Also you cannot multiply both sides of an inequality by negative numbers, so multiplying by $xy$ is not legitimate.

A correct proof: $2|xy|\leq x^{2}+y^{2}$ because $(|x|-|y|)^{2} \geq 0$. Hence $|\frac {xy} {\sqrt {x^{2}+y^{2}}}| \leq \frac 1 2\sqrt {x^{2}+y^{2}}$. Can you complete the proof now?

Comment: Not quite, I still have a few questions. How did you transform $2|xy| \le{x^2+y^2}$ to $$|\frac{xy} {\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}| \le \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$

Edit: What I am having trouble is understanding how to transform the usual AM-GM inequality to fit my problem here

You divided both sides by two, but what next? Thanks for your response, now I see my faults!

Comment: I divided by 2 and also by square root of $x^{2}+y^{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $:$ Observe that $$\left | \frac {xy} {\sqrt {x^2+y^2}}\right |\leq \sqrt {x^2 + y^2}.$$

Note that $$\frac {1} {\sqrt {x^2+y^2}} \not\leq \sqrt {x^2 + y^2}$$ for all $x,y \in \Bbb R.$ For instance take $x=y=\frac 1 2.$

Also note that you cannot say $$\frac {xy} {\sqrt {x^2+y^2}} \not\geq 0$$ for all $x,y \in \Bbb R.$ For instance you may take $x$ and $y$ in such a way that $xy < 0.$

Comment: You need absolute values in your inequality.

Comment: No matter @Kavi Rama Murthy sir. Because $x \leq |x| \leq \sqrt {x^2 + y^2}$ and $y \leq |y| \leq \sqrt {x^2+y^2}.$ So we have $$\frac {xy} {\sqrt {x^2 + y^2}} \leq \frac {|xy|} {\sqrt {x^2+y^2}} \leq \sqrt {x^2 + y^2}.$$

Comment: If $f(x,y) \leq g(x,y)$ and $g(x,y) \to 0$ you cannot say $f(x,y) \to 0$. You need  a lower bound also.

Comment: Yeah that's correct. But my previous inequality was also equally valid.

Answer (score 0):

You may make the squeezing easier using AM-GM:

So, let $xy \neq 0$ (otherwise the expression evaluates anyway to $0$ for $x^2+y^2 \neq 0$)

$$0 \leq \left|\frac{xy}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} \right| \stackrel{AM-GM}{\leq} \frac{|xy|}{\sqrt{2\sqrt{x^2y^2}}} = \frac{\sqrt{|xy|}}{\sqrt{2}}\stackrel{(x,y)\to (0,0)}{\longrightarrow}0$$

Comment: Could you elaborate further? How do you know that $$|\frac{xy}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}|$$ is lower or equal than AM-GM?

Comment: Just a moment. Will answer soon.

Comment: AM-GM states for $a,b \geq 0: \frac{a+b}{2}\geq \sqrt{ab}$. So, for $a,b > 0 $ it follows $\frac{1}{a+b} \leq \frac{1}{2\sqrt{ab}}$. Now, set $a=x^2, b=y^2$ and note that $\sqrt{x^2y^2} = |xy|$. $\stackrel{AM-GM}{\leq}$ means, that I apply AM-GM in this step.

Answer (score 0):

Option :

Let $(x,y) \not =(0,0)$.

Note:

$|x| =\sqrt{x^2} \le \sqrt{x^2+y^2};$

Likewise : $|y| \le \sqrt{x^2+y^2}.$

$0 <\left | \dfrac{xy}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} \right| \le $

$\dfrac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}.$

Given $\epsilon >0$, choose $\delta =\epsilon$.